# Java Swing one-row scrollable container?

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing an app, that needs some kind of one-row JList to store formula objects. I first tried with just buttons as objects with text on them, but it was not good. Then I made one-row JList but all it's cells have the same width, and it looks like this

[image]

(a scrollable area). So "<" will have the same width as others and it looks bad.
Is there a way to force list cells to use their real width? Or there is any cool container that just can store objects(just text) with scrolling over them?

With buttons it looks like

[image]

Comment: *(just text)* - how about a JTextArea?

Comment: Well, that's the worst case, that's why I was looking for something that could store objects separately.

Comment: *first tried with just buttons as objects with text on them, but it was not good* - well, we don't know what "not good" means. We don't know what your are expecting. How about a  simple JPanel with a FlowLayout and you add JLabel components with your text?

Comment: I added picture of how it looks with buttons. Well, if there is no way, I'll use with buttons.

Comment: *if there is no way* - if there is no way what??? You still haven't statement what you don't like about the buttons or about what your actual requirement is!

Comment: if there is no way to make JList with cells, which have their normal width instead of max between all cell widths. I like buttons, if there's a way to fit each cell to it's normal width it would be just perfect

Answer (score 0):

How about you use the `JTable` which you can configure it to have a single row?

**Example Code:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 
import javax.swing.JTable; 
  
public class JTableTest { 
    JFrame f; 
    JTable j; 
  
    JTableTest() 
    { 
     
        f = new JFrame(); 
  
        f.setTitle("JTable Example"); 
  
        String[][] data = { 
            { "F=ma", "e=mc^2", "a^2=b^2+c^2" }
        }; 
  
        String[] columnNames = { "Newton", "Einstein", "Pythagoras" }; 
  
 
        j = new JTable(data, columnNames); 
        j.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300); //Position x,y & Size of JTable height,width
  
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
        f.add(sp); 
  
        f.setSize(500, 200); 

        f.setVisible(true); 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new JTableTest(); 
    } 
}
```

By default, the width of `JTable` cells are fixed. You can change them, however, using:

```
j.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(5); //Set Width=5 for first column
```

Comment: There is a header, so it's not a formula, it's a table

Comment: If the title is what is bothering you, you can just ignore the statement   f.setTitle("JTable Example");

Comment: No, I mean a table header - column names

Comment: add j.setTableHeader(null); This would remove the header.